# Wordpress - get tags for posts with custom field

Tags: wordpress, tags

I have a custom field, say, "mood", and I need to display list of tags for all posts that have "mood" = "grumpy". Is it possible to do this without fetching all posts and then fetching tags for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function get_posts();

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'        => 'mood',
    'meta_value'      => 'grumpy',
);

$your_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: But then I'll have to make wp_get_post_tags for each post, and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should achieve what you want. Just look out for typos and missed semi-colons!

While you don't get the whole post, you do still have to query the database for the ID of posts with 'mood' = 'grumpy', so unless you have lots of posts, it's probably easier to just go with the answer @Dorel gave.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare('
    SELECT ID
    FROM %1$s
    LEFT JOIN %2$s
    ON %1$s.ID = %2$s.post_id
    WHERE %2$s.meta_key = "mood"
    AND %2$s.meta_value = "grumpy"
    ', $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
);
$ids = $wpdb->get_col($query);

if(!empty($ids)) : foreach($ids as $post_id) :

        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post_id, $args);
        if(!empty($ids)) : foreach($tags as $tag) :

                $tags[] = $tag->name;

            endforeach;
        endif;

    endforeach;
endif;

// Now you have an array of Tag names, output them as you wish
```

Codex for `wp_get_post_tags` = http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags
Codex for `wp_get_object_terms` (to see what `$args` are available for `wp_get_post_tags`) = 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms#Argument_Options

Comment: Ok, I implemented it the same way, but this still fetches tags for each post separately, but it seems that there's no easy other way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you have to fetch tags for each post seperately. There is no link between your meta_key and the tags, so you have to reference post. Once you have the Array of tags though, you can manipulate it as you wish (so only one instance of each is shown, sort them alphabetically, etc.).